# Reinstall a clean copy of Mavericks AND migrate my Apps and Settings?

Tags: macos, migration, install

**Background:** I bought a new laptop with Mavericks installed and used Migration Assistant to restore my environment from a Time Machine backup. It worked fine except that all the bungling I've done trying to get a working Python dev environment set up also got restored, along with a bunch of other system level junk I've installed.

Trying again for a clean system, today I wiped the drive, reinstalled Mavericks and made sure not to check "Computer and Network Settings" in the Migration Assistant dialog but I still ended up with a bunch of system level stuff I don't want (e.g. Python framework installed in my user 'Library' folder (not Apple's Python in the `System/Library` but what got installed from Python.org installer).

**My question:** I'd like to be sure I am starting fresh. Is there any way, short of rebuilding my settings and environment manually to get a clean Mavericks install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise the following:

1. Make a backup of the current state of the machine, this time using [**Time Machine's Exclusions Option**](http://pondini.org/TM/10.html) to remove the offending files (e.g ~/Library/*/python) from the backup.
2. Holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at the startup chime, boot into [OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718) and erase the startup volume using Disk Utility.
3. Cleanly [reinstall OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph13871) on the empty volume
4. Once complete, use [Setup Assistant (not Migration Assistant!)](http://pondini.org/OSX/Setup.html) to restore the Time Machine Backup.

**Notes:**

- You can only restore complete backups -not incremental. The TM backup mentioned in (1) must be a complete backup.
- Be wary of what you exclude and only exclude what is necessary. For example, excluding the /System folder will prevent you from performing a full restore via Setup Assistant.
- Why not Migration Assistant? [It's prone to cause problems when doing a clean restore.](http://pondini.org/OSX/MigrationProblems.html)
- The Pondini links provided are for Mountain Lion. All the instructions work *exactly the same* in Mavericks and are completely applicable.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am going to start fresh and rebuild manually – too many items which I may have installed, etc. I've cloned my drive so nothing will be lost. Just chalk it up to spring cleaning.